# GhostScript: Windows 7 conversion succeeds where Linux fails

Tags: linux, windows-7, ghostscript

I am using `Ghostscript 9.05` to generate images from PDFs as part of an application (run as a process in Java).

I recently came across an issue where a few PDF to image conversions failed on a linux box with the following error:

```
**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by:
**** >>>> Acrobat Distiller 8.3.1 (Macintosh) <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF 
**** specification.
```

With each page throwing a similar error to this:

```
**** Warning: File has insufficient data for an image.
%%BoundingBox: 77 36 797 1082
%%HiResBoundingBox: 77.760003 36.720001 796.320030 1081.440041
Page 141
warning: ignoring invalid option raw
error: cannot decode code stream
unable to decode JPX image data.
```

However, when running the same conversions locally on a Win7 machine the error does not occur.

I know the short and narrow of it is "*send the PDF back and get them to send you a working one*" - but I am intrigued as to why this would fail on a linux box but succeed without error (and producing error-less images) on a Windows machine?

Any ideas?

I am reluctant to open a bug report at this time as there may be a significant difference between the Linux and WIndows versions of which I am unaware.

#### Update

After looking how Ghostscript has been built on our Linux box (we are running Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Long Term Support release), I have gathered the following information:

For jpeg2000 manipulation Ghostscript is using the JasPer JPEG-2000 runtime libraries version 1.900.1-13 (ISO reference implementation of JPEG-2000 Part-1).

JasPer is built using libjpeg-turbo8 libraries.

According to the [JasPer website](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/)

> The JasPer software has been included in the JPEG-2000 Part-5 standard (i.e., ISO/IEC 15444-5), as an official reference implementation of the JPEG-2000 Part-1 codec.

Ghostscript is listed as one of the projects known to use JasPer. It appears Ubuntu are using JasPer, the ISO reference implementation, and the Ubuntu package source for Ghostscript lists JasPer (libjasper-dev) as a dependency for building, not openJPEG. [[source]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/ghostscript)

At the moment it looks like the only option is to try different versions of linux, building ghostscript versions and testing them.

Comment: Cannot possibly give any help without seeing an example PDF file. However teh %%BoundingBox commetns are suspicious, I wouldn't expect to see those in a PDF file.

Comment: @KenS: he might have used Ghostscript to send the PDF to the `bbox` device  :-)

Comment: @My Head Hurts: You can find out the respective Ghostscript versions like this: (1) on Windows use `gswin32c.exe -v` or `gswin64c.exe -v`;  (2) on Linux use `gs -v`.

Comment: Ghostscript no longer uses JasPer, because it is slow, memory hungry, full of bugs, difficult to work with and (apparently) no longer maintained. We now use OpenJPEG instead, I would recommend using the current released version of Ghostscript (9.06) which definitely uses OpenJPEG rather than JasPer. If you build GS from source, then it will use the OpenJPEG source which we include in the source distribution, and all should be well. According to the documentation file History9.htm, the 9.05 release of GS used OpenJPEG instead of JasPer.

Comment: @KenS That sounds like a good reason not to use JasPer. I'll try with GS 9.6 and let you know how it goes. Thanks again for the informative responses.

Comment: If you have any problems, can you use irc to talk about it ? We run the #ghostscript channel on irc.freenode.net, and all the GS developers hang around there. In particular our build maintainer is there (he and I both live in the UK), and people a great deal more knowledgeable about Linux than me....

Comment: @KenS Thanks - I've never used irc but I will try it out in future, it sounds like a useful place to hang around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you are running 64-bit Linux and 32-bit Windows binaries.

However the most likely problem is that your Linux distribution has chosen to build Ghostscript with 'shared libraries'. Certain 3rd party libraries used by Ghostscript (eg FReeType, Litle CMS etc) can be linked dynamically instead of statically, and loaded at run-time.

I notice that the images are JPX (JPEG 2000), and these will use the OpenJPEG library. *However* the source code for OpenJPEG shipped with Ghostscript is not the 1.5 version, it is 1.5 plus some bits pulled from the forthcoming 2.0 plus some fixes we needed to add (and fed upstream, we believe they will be incorporated into 2.0). We hope to be using a standard version of this code in the near future, when the next version is released.

If your Linux distribution has chosen to build Ghostscript with OpenJPEG as a shared library, then you won't get the benefit of those source changes, and the JPX decoder won't work as well. The Windows build of GS doesn't have an 'out-of-the-box' method to build 3rd party libraries as DLLs, and so (unless you do a lot of work yourself) it always uses the source code for the 3rd party libraries which we supply.

If you build GS yourself from source (on Linux), then you may well find that this behaves perfectly well. I would also venture to suggest that there is nothing actually wrong with the PDF files, just the version of OpenJPEG being used.

We do something like 60,000 tests every time we make a commit to the Ghostscript repository, but obviously we do these tests against the code which we actually ship. At least it means we have a reasonable degree of confidence in what we send out, provided you use the code we supply. We *don't* recommend building Ghostscript with shared libraries, but nothing we say persuades the various Linux distributors otherwise, so its something we have to live with.

Comment: +1 very informative answer, thank you very much. Ghostscript has always been great for me so I had an inkling that there might be more too it. I'll have a look at how GS has been built on Linux and provide some feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi KenS - I have updated my answer with some information about our GS build on linux if you wouldn't mind taking a look? Also, we noticed that the next version 9.6 doesn’t list any jpeg-2000 libraries as compile dependancies - is there some other magic working in there or is it integrated into libjpeg-turbo8?

Comment: I can't really tell you much about how Linux distributors work (and any dependency list for packages is nothing to do with us). I added a comment above about OpenJPEG being our default since 9.05. I believe it is possible to still use JasPer (though I can't see why anyone would want to). If I remember correctly there's a new version of Ubuntu due out any time, and we had some discussions with one of the maintainers recently about dependencies, so hopefully that will be straightened out. I'd still recommend building from our source (because its better tested I feel), but that's up to you.

Comment: I've now tried out GS 9.6 using the test/eval download (wanted to try it out before building it) and everything seems to be working beautifully. Thanks for all your help, it is greatly appreciated.